# My app redirects me to a page, but I can't get to it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link'
///------------------------PAGES-------------------------------///
import {default as Main} from '../app/sections/Main.js'

export default function Home() {

const [site, setSite] = useState('down');

const mainprops = {
site,
setSite
};

if (site == 'up') {
return(

<Main {...mainprops}/>

)}
else if (site =='down') {
return(

## Demo headline

About Us

)}
};

Comment: Hi Saim, could I suggest you clarify your question in the question body? Here you have only shared unformatted code with no real signs as to 1) what your issue is, 2) where you think it's coming from, 3) what you've already tried in order to fix it…This question needs more detail.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.